# How can i replace a tag with video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace `<a href="123" .......>text</a>` with `<video src="123"..... />`
How can i do this with jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or I assume you want to replace the a tags after clicking?
NOTE: I replace the 'video' tag with div, just for making it easier for you to see the change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toVideo').live('click', function(e){
        $(this).replaceWith('<div src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">new video</div>');
        e.preventDefault();  
    })
})
```

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9xHS/5/

Or if you want to replace all tags, maybe you can:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toVideo').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith('<div src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + $(this).attr('href') + '</div>');
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A9R3L/1/

Comment: I don't know, but someone downvoted all answers, including mine

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $a = $("a");
   $("<video/>").attr("src", $a.attr("href")).after($a);   
   $a.remove();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you don't have src attribute on a tags

Comment: @Edgar, I think there is still another issue in your code: if there are more than one <a> tags (with different href), your code will generate the same video to replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery's `replaceAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/)